# iOS app open screen to app flashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that is built and working fine. I have added the launch images, but now when the app transitions from the launch image to the actual app it flashes (aka their isnt' a smooth transition).  The funny thing is my launch screen is my the same view as the initial view shown. How I made my launch images is by running the app in the simulator and the going to File > Save screen shot, then dragged them into xcode.

Comment: The problem is most likely how you set up your initial window in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in an open source class I am using

```
//Fade in
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.alpha = 1;
}];
```

Removed it and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have uses for splahscreen.
Set this code in Appdelegate class.
It runs smoothly.

```
- (void)showSplashView
{
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-80, -80, self.window.frame.size.width+160.0, self.window.frame.size.height+160.0);
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Here 'splashView is a simple UIImageView' and you can use your image name in place of default png.